# how to print out the nth row of pascal's triangle using 1d arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

it should be a program that will print the row of the pascal's triangle depending on the user input, so if the user enters 4, the output will be: 1 3 3 1. i've figured out how to print out the entire pascal's triangle, but i'm not sure how to adjust it so that it only prints out the nth row.

```
public class PascalTriangle
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        int x=1;
        int y=0;
        int[] pascal = new int[num];
        int[] pascalTemp = new int[num];
        pascal[0] = 1;
        pascal[1] = 1;

        for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
            {
                if(i==0)
                    System.out.print("1");
                else
                {
                    if(j==0 || j==i)
                        System.out.print("1 ");
                    else
                    {
                        pascalTemp[x] = pascal[y] + pascal[y+1];
                        System.out.print(pascalTemp[x]+ " ");
                        x++;
                        y++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            pascalTemp[x] = 1;
            if(i>1)
            {
                y=0;
                pascal[y]=1;
                for(x=1, y=1; y<=i; x++, y++)
                    pascal[y] = pascalTemp[x];
                x=1;
                y=0;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only print when i == num-1 using if statements?

Comment: @tgdavies which print statements would i place that in front of? when i just use the "if (i==num-1)" before the "System.out.print(pascalTemp[x]+ " ");" , it works but it also prints out the 1, 1 1, 1 1, 1 1, ... until that row, which i don't want

Comment: Let me start with an off-topic suggestion: Instead of printing each value as it is calculated, append the values to a `CharSequence` object until you have finished a row. Then, print that row .

Comment: If you use the suggestion about not printing until you have a complete row, the suggestion from @tgdavies will be easier to implement.

Comment: You'd need to surround each and every print statement which is inside your loop with that if statement. Building up a String so that you only need one print statement is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The r-th number of the n-th line (r = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...) is `(n - 1)Cr = (n - 1)! / (r! * (n - 1 - r)!)` . `(n - 1)C0` is always `1`. And `(n - 1)C(r + 1)` can be obtained from `(n - 1)Cr`. For example, when `n = 4`, it becomes as follows.

```
3C0 = 1           = 1
3C1 = 3C0 * 3 / 1 = 3
3C2 = 3C1 * 2 / 2 = 3
3C3 = 3C2 * 1 / 3 = 1
```

Multiplying numbers decrease by 1 and dividing numbers increase by 1.
If you program this, it will be as follows.

```
static void pascalNthRow(int n) {
    for (int p = 1, m = n - 1, d = 1; d <= n; p = p * m / d, --m, ++d)
        System.out.print(p + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

and

```
pascalNthRow(3);
pascalNthRow(4);
pascalNthRow(5);
```

output

```
1 2 1 
1 3 3 1 
1 4 6 4 1
```